# R: How to plot the average of each age group

Tags: r, plot, mean, standard-deviation

I have a data set that has three columns: Age, Gender, Shoes. The shoes column refers to how many pairs of shoes an observation owns. I want to graph the average number of shoes owned per age group with the standard deviations of the shoes. I have created a graph, but I do not know if I generated this. Here is a little bit of my data set:

```
  Shoes Gender Age
1    50 Female  57
2     2   Male  27
3     4   Male  22
4     6 Female  19
5     4   Male  24
6    40 Female  28
```

Here is the code I wrote to generate my desired graph:

```
 x <- summarySE(data, measurevar="Shoes", groupvars=c("Gender","Age" ))

 ggplot(x,aes(x=Age, y=Shoes, color=Gender)) + 
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Shoes-se, ymax=Shoes+se), width=.1) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_point()
```

[image]

I know the ages are hard to read on the bottom, but they go 10,11,12,13...91 and above. Does this graph show average number of shoes owned per age with the standard deviations of the shoes surrounding each mean point?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: It looks like you are plotting +/- the standard error not +/- the standard deviation.

Comment: Am I plotting the average number of shoes owned per age?